# Recursive function stopped after the first loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, recursion

## Context

I update several sites with Ajax calls, one by one to conserve the server.

I made a recursive function that runs himself again when an Ajax call is completed.

## Issue

The function is stopped after the first loop.

Any idea ?

## Code

```javascript
var updateSite = function (site) {
    if (site.status == 'waiting for update') {
        updateStatus(i, site, 'update in progress');

        $.get(site.url)
            .success(function () {
                updateStatus(i, site, 'updated');
            })
            .error(function () {
                updateStatus(i, site, 'not updated');
            })
            .complete(function () {
                updateSite(allSites[i++]);
            });
    }
};

var i = 0;

updateSite(allSites[i]);
```

Comment: @Amberlamps -- the next call is initiated by the .complete function

Comment: @LarryK: Thanks! I am obviously not used to jQuery :)

Comment: @GG -- be sure to test in multiple browsers, especially IE

Comment: @LarryK: This is an internal tool, if it works on chrome that's ok. :)

Comment: @GG: If you use `allSites.shift()` instead of `allSites[i]` you would not need `i` in the first place, but I guess you need `i` for further processing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change complete function as below:

```
function () {
     updateSite(allSites[++i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Any error messages?

Perhaps the var `updateSite` is not yet defined when the anonymous function you're using for complete is defined.

Try this:

```
var updateSite;
updateSite = function (site) {
    if (site.status == 'waiting for update') {
        updateStatus(i, site, 'update in progress');
.... // everything else the same...
```